# Connection to tcp://localhost:8554?timeout=0 failed: Cannot assign requested address

Tags: docker, rtsp

I have two docker containers. The first one I run using this command:

```
docker run -d --network onprem_network --name rtsp_simple_server --rm -t -e RTSP_PROTOCOLS=tcp -p 8554:8554 aler9/rtsp-simple-server
```

The second docker is created from these files:
**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM python:slim-buster
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
WORKDIR /code
COPY rtsp_streaming.py /code/
COPY ConsoleCapture_clipped.mp4 /code
RUN apt update && apt-get update && apt install ffmpeg -y # && apt-get install ffmpeg libsm6 libxext6  -y
CMD ["python", "/code/rtsp_streaming.py"]
```

**rtsp_streaming.py:**

```
import os
os.system("ffmpeg -re -stream_loop 0 -i ConsoleCapture_clipped.mp4 -c copy -f rtsp rtsp://localhost:8554/mystream")
```

I run the second docker container like so:

```
docker run --network onprem_network -v ${data_folder}:/code/Philips_MR --name rtsp_streaming -d rtsp_streaming
```

**docker ps -a yields:**

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                      COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                      PORTS                    NAMES
48ea091b870d   rtsp_streaming             "python /code/rtsp_s…"   18 minutes ago   Exited (0) 18 minutes ago                            rtsp_streaming
5376e070f89f   aler9/rtsp-simple-server   "/rtsp-simple-server"    19 minutes ago   Up 19 minutes               0.0.0.0:8554->8554/tcp   rtsp_simple_server
```

The second container exits quickly with this error:

> Connection to tcp://localhost:8554?timeout=0 failed: Cannot assign
> requested address

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: You should use `rtsp_simple_server:8554` instead of `localhost`. Did you try that

Comment: Thank you!  Solved that issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `rtsp_simple_server:8554` instead of `localhost`.

Since in the container called `rtsp_streaming`, `localhost` means `rtsp_streaming` and in `rtsp_simple_server`, `localhost means` rtsp_simple_server`. So you should use the container's name.